# c# implementing an interface to operate running program commandline style

Tags: c#, wpf, external

I am using [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) to parse command line arguments.

This allows me to call my WPF Application with different startup options like open Formular `Foo` with `Entity X`. This works.

I wonder how I might implement an interface which allows injecting a command line argument in the running application.

I guess I'd have to look-up the process and call a method `CustomCommandlineProcessing(string)` on it, passing the arguments I need.

#### Questions

- How can I implement a method that can be called external?
- How do I call it on the running Application?
- Do I need to take note of anything special?

  - e.g. special access to the GUI Thread (beside the normal async stuff)?

Just comment requesting me to qualify my Questions.

Comment: If you are passing it to a running WPF application then it will not be a command line argument...

Comment: @milney I know that. The Idea is to pass a command line argument like string. I don't even know if this is necessary, or if I can also pass objects. Propably i need to create a console application passing the arguments inside the running application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is already running, then anything you 'pass' to it will not be a command line argument...

You probably want to look into inter-process communication;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

The most common methods would be a web interface, a socket or named pipe, a memory-mapped file or a shared database.

Comment: Doesn't exist a way to call a Method inside another Program? Anyway thank you, i guess i'll need to read something about the topics you mentioned.

Comment: No, sadly it isn't that easy :( I wish you could simply do that... The old way to do this was through COM etc. but you really don't want to get into that as it is very complicated. It will depend on your use case but for very simple cases (like just calling a method as you alluded) you can make use of a Memeory Mapped File, or a Socket or Named Pipe, and for more complex cases (moving more data across) you should look into a shared Cache or Database layer, or a web interface

Comment: As it is a requirement only to pass a string, Im going ahead and informing myself about Memory Mapped File, Socket or Named Pipe, Technology. Thanks man, it was really comprehensive to my case. At the time I asked my question I was thinking of a really easy way, as simple as you can call COM Functions out of c#.